# I cannot read a file from path in java

Tags: java, file, text

I'm trying to put the contents of a text file into a string. But every time I run it, the file is not found.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = ""; 
        try {
            Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/User/Desktop/Counties/Adair_County,_Oklahoma.txt"));
            text = x.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("File Not Found");
        }
        System.out.print(text);
    }
}
```

Above is the program, can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: The name of the file seems suspicious. To make sure the folder exists, try `System.out.println(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/User/Desktop/Counties/").exists())`

Comment: I'm sure it exists, I created the text file.

Comment: The developer is almost always wrong. So admit you're wrong, and find why. Please run the snippet and check the result

Comment: BTW, instead of printing a custom (and sometimes unrelevant) message, don't catch the exception and let it propagate, or rethrow it using `new RuntimeException(e)`

Comment: Ok, so the folder exists. Do what I said for the exception, and see the real message

Comment: It's probably that comma in the file name

Comment: The name of the file is weird, yes.

Comment: No, it is not the comma. How do you use RuntimeException?

Comment: Instead of `System.out.print("File Not Found");`, write `new RuntimeException(e)`, or simply remove the try-catch block and add `thows IOException to the signature of the main`. I just want to know the exact exception.

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
 at Reader.main(Reader.java:12)

Comment: So the file is here :D You hid the real problem by catching all kinds of exceptions and printing a wrong message. Remember that next time, don't do it again

Comment: Your file does not seem to have any line. Is it empty ?

Comment: No, it is not empty. Something is wrong with my code, not the file I think.

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` suggests there is no newline character in the file. Your file is either empty or contains only one line

Comment: I agree with @Dici, your file seems to be empty. To satisfy oneself of the file emptiness, just print a full stacktrace or at least exception's message. It'll be for en empty file "No line found"

Answer (score -2):

The below code will create a new file at desired location.Via FileWriter contents are written into it.
Note: write() doesn't has an in-built new-line feature.After writing, flush() it and close the connection(FileWriter). Then use FileReader to read the contents from that file. Get the total length of the content stored in that file, store it in a character array.Close the connection. Pass it to String type and print that String.
Since FileWriter and FileReader are **Raw API** ,I'll recommend you to use BufferedWriter and BufferedReader as they are **Refined API**.

```
class FileReader
{
      public static void main(String args[])
      throws IOException
      {
        File f1 = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/User/Desktop/Counties/Adair_County,_Oklahoma.txt"));
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(f1);
        out.write("SENSELESS");
        out.write("CODE");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        FileReader.in = new FileReader(f1);
        long size = f1.length();
        char[x] = new char[(int)size];
        in.read(x);
        in.close();
        String s1 = new String(x);
        System.out.println(s1);
 }
       }
```

Comment: Can you please remove that senseless piece of code with no explanation ?